# How to change multiple values at the same time using ramdajs

Tags: ramda.js

I am new to ramdajs.
Let's say I have an object:

```
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

I can do this to change a to 11:

```
  const aLens = R.lensProp('a');
  R.set(aLens, 11, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3});
```

How do I change a to 11 and b to 22 with just one call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just need to update the keys with known values, one option is to use [`R.merge`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#merge):

```
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}

R.merge(obj, {a: 11, b: 22}) //=> {"a": 11, "b": 22, "c": 3}
```

If you need to update the object based on their existing values then you could use [`R.evolve`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve) instead.

```
const abAdder = R.evolve({
  a: add(10),
  b: add(20)
})

abAdder(obj) //=> {"a": 11, "b": 22, "c": 3}
```

You could also create this as a lens, though unless you plan on composing it with other lenses the benefit over the above options is questionable.

```
const projectLens = keys => R.lens(R.pick(keys), R.flip(R.merge))

const abLens = projectLens(['a', 'b']);

R.set(abLens, { a: 11, b: 22 }, obj) //=> {"a": 11, "b": 22, "c": 3}
R.view(abLens, obj) //=> {"a": 1, "b": 2}
```

Comment: +1 for `projectLens`.  I don't know that I'd have much use for it personally, but I like seeing how it could be done relatively easily.

Comment: Do you know if merge is faster than piping/composing lenses?  Is projectLens another way of piping lenses?

Comment: Since I am using R.merge right now to solve my current problem.  I am setting this as accepted answer.

Comment: If you don't need to compose lenses together then `R.merge` will be faster if used directly. This is because `projectLens` in the example shown here will end up making use of `R.merge` as well, so it can't be any faster.

Comment: I believe there is an extra `R.` in front of `keys` for the `projectLens` implementation. I mean it should be: 
`const projectLens = keys => R.lens(R.pick(keys), R.flip(R.merge))`

And personally I would prefer something more defensive for the setter, like `const projectLens = keys => R.lens(R.pick(keys), (x, s) => R.merge(s, R.pick(keys, x)))`

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can't really do it with lenses.  Lenses focus on on single part of a data structure.

Ramda's [`evolve`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve) might **[do the trick](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20foo%20%3D%20%7Ba%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%202%2C%20c%3A%203%7D%3B%0Aevolve%28%7Ba%3A%20always%2811%29%2C%20b%3A%20always%2822%29%7D%29%28foo%29)**:

```
const foo = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
evolve({a: always(11), b: always(22)})(foo)// => {a: 11, b: 22, c: 3}
```

But I think you need to consider what you mean by "in a single call".  Ramda offers [`compose`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose) and [`pipe`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipe) (as well as some more obscure alternatives) to allow you to build up a single function out of several calls.  If you call the resulting function, you are still making a single call, but in a very real sense, you're calling all the functions that you included in your pipeline.

Thus,

```
const fn = pipe(
  set(lensProp('a'), 11),
  set(lensProp('b'), 22)
);
fn({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}); //=> {a: 11, b: 22, c: 3}
```

And yet that's **[a "single call"](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20fn%20%3D%20pipe%28%0A%20%20set%28lensProp%28%27a%27%29%2C%2011%29%2C%0A%20%20set%28lensProp%28%27b%27%29%2C%2022%29%0A%29%3B%0A%0Afn%28%7Ba%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%202%2C%20c%3A%203%7D%29%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%7Ba%3A%2011%2C%20b%3A%2022%2C%20c%3A%203%7D)** to `fn`.

Comment: Do you know if there is any performance difference between using evolve and pipe?

Comment: @techguy2000: I don't know.  I would only worry about that if I tested and found this to be a bottleneck in my code... which seems unlikely here.

Comment: OK. That makes sense.  Thanks you for answering my original question and giving me insight!

Answer (score 0):

actually there is a way to do this with lens, but using lens in such position might not be the best option.

logically `R.set` returns the whole object. so it could be repeated several times(chained) to perform the task you need:

```
const aLens = R.lensProp('a');
const bLens = R.lensProp('b');
R.set(bLens, 22)(R.set(aLens, 11)({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}));
```

or for a better visualization:

```
const aLens = R.lensProp('a');
const bLens = R.lensProp('b');
R.compose(R.set(bLens, 22), R.set(aLens,11))({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with merge and curry:

```
curry(merge(__, {a:11, b:22}))({a:1, b:2, c:3});
```

I prefer to make this util function:

```
const overwrite = R.curry((over, org) => R.merge(R.__, over)(org));

overwrite({a:11, b:22}, {a:1, b:2, c:3});
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the cookbook:
https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Cookbook#assocpaths

```js
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

const assocPaths = R.pipe(R.zipWith(R.assocPath), R.flip(R.reduce(R.applyTo)));

assocPaths(["a", "b"], [11, 22])(obj) //=> {"a": 11, "b": 22, "c": 3}
```

Unlike evolve, assocPaths cant do updates based on existing values. However, if your new values are static then assocPaths might be more simple than to create the transformation function for R.evolve (see below).

```js
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

const newValues = [{id: "a", newValue: 11}, {id: "b", newValue: 22}];

const transformations = R.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return {
    ...acc,
    [curr.id]: x => curr.newValue  // or update based on current value
  }
}, {}, newValues);  // {{"a":  x  => 11}, {"b": x => 22}}

console.log(
  R.evolve(transformations, obj)  
);  // { "a": 11, "b": 22, "c": 3}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```